# Process controlling file sharing windows 7

Tags: windows-7, samba, file-sharing

I want to know which process do control file sharing over LAN (like samba on linux) in windows 7.
I think it's some of `svchost`s.
The goal is speed-up file sharing to get rid of lags while watching films from shared folder on TV.
-- **UPDATE**:
The process hacker says it's windows kernel directly, so there's no way.
Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve by understanding what services are required to be running for SMB functionality to be enabled on Windows 7.  In order to properly answer this question, we must know exactly which version of SMB your Samba server is configured to use, there is only a service that controls if SMB functionality is enabled or disabled (other than the feature being installed).  Without this information your question cannot be answered.

Comment: I suspect your question is suffering from the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) (also see the [XY problem on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445)). Considering revising it to focus on the problem you're trying to solve rather than your proposed solution.

Comment: May be related to the SMB.sys driver.

Comment: Might be better to use Windows server 2102, it has SMB Direct....https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/smb-direct

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I am aware of XY problem. The 2nd line in the OP is for better goal understanding. Should I rename question to "How to speed-up file sharing"?

Comment: @Moab Windows server -- nope, it's desktop for gaming and work.

Comment: @Ramhound -- native windows file sharing. Where do I get all necessary information about it?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin - Be more specific.

Comment: It seems you're trying to speed up file sharing. Instead of asking *which process...control file sharing over LAN* you would make better progress if you explained the problem you're facing and asked how to improve the speed of the file sharing.

Comment: Maybe you can go to Manage on your server and see the Connections that are currently connected to your server and you can disconnect them. BTW if you use an old Samba it may use SMB1 and the performance relate to that